# How do I customize the Ext.grid.RowBodyFeature of ExtJS 4.0?

Tags: extjs4

I have implemented the `getAdditionalData` in ExtJS's `grid.panel`.

I have it showing the extra information but I want to style the extra row.  Basically make the font smaller, etc.

Other than wrapping my data in `span` tags, is there another way to alter the style for those rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  It was just easier to use a custom `renderer`.